# How do I get rid of this annoying axis?

Tags: rigging, axis

I'm working on a Roblox rig in Blender. Everytime I set the pivot point (origin) to the selected mesh of the bones, an axis seems to be following it and showing up anywhere I set the origin of the object. It also appears under the root bone. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Just to be clear, which axis are you talking about? The red-green-blue transform widget, the big white X-Y-Z thing, or something else?

Comment: It seems to be an **empty** type of axis that I never even added. I don't see it anywhere in the outliner either.

Comment: That's interesting. Not even parented to the bone or something? If it's not anywhere in the scene, did you enable any addons? (Blender comes preinstalled with quite a few.)

Comment: Or if not, perhaps the file has an embedded Python script that runs automatically when you open the file. (Can't remember if that's on by default, but you can turn it off.)

Comment: I just fixed the problem. I simply went into "Properties", went to the "Object" section of the bones and unchecked "Axis" under **Display**. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're quite welcome, although I didn't do all that much. (: Would you mind taking the time to write up an answer to your question? It'll let people know that your problem's been fixed, and it'll help other people who come here with the same problem.

Comment: (I'd do it, but then I'd be getting all the fake internet points instead of you, and that wouldn't be very fair. :D)

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the problem. I realized that I had "Axis" checked under "Display" while looking at the properties of the object.